# How to store a value from a textbox that has external control source into main form in access?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a text box named "Amount" which values come from another textbox in the subform. 
I want to store the "Amount" value into "PayableAmount" Field. 
The control source for Amount is

```
=[Order Details Subform].[Form]![PayableAmountInv]
```

How do I store this subform into PayableAmount field? I have tried many things i.e using vba to .value.

Comment: Show your attempted code. What event did you use? Simply: `Me!PayableAmount = Me.Amount`. Why are you saving data in multiple locations?

Comment: Also explain what you are trying to do as clearly as you can.  Show the relevant tables and forms then explain what you want to happen.